# I have a HTML submit button and am trying to send hidden info to an outside form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML submit button and am trying to send hidden info to an outside form.

```
<form name="input" action="https://www.skinnybodycare.com/aff/join" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="2skinnyme" name="enroller" />
    <input type="hidden" value="Continue">
    <input type="submit" value="Order Now">
</form>
```

And it has to take the user to https://www.skinnybodycare.com/aff/join and input the value and click on Continue... but can't figure it out and I'm against time here... help is very much appreciated...

I also want to say that I've already searched the forum for similar issues but couldn't find anything

Comment: What is your actual problem/question?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here.  This should post these two values to the form action successfully.  (Though I'm not sure how you expect to "click" a hidden element.)

Comment: The action url https://www.skinnybodycare.com/aff is "not found on this server"

Comment: I have a HTML submit button and am trying to send hidden info to an outside from

Comment: Are you saying you want a click on "Order Now" on your page to take the user to a different page and automatically fill in an input and click a button on that second page?

Comment: That is correct nnnnn!

Comment: What you want is impossible exactly because of people like you.

Comment: I'm sorry, why is that Niels?

Comment: you're trying to post information to someone else's form action, this is a breach of security. I'm sure they will have something in place to stop this kind of behavior. And if you don't understand that `<input type="hidden" value="Continue">` is totally redundant, then you should be trying to 'inject' information into other people's forms....

Comment: That form is made especially for that, for info to be passed to it. It has to have the referral name in it so that it takes the correct entry further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: You can't pre-fill forms from outside, unless you've made code that reads values from the URL.
Here's some sample code (untested) to give you an idea of how to make the page work this way:

```
<form name="input" action="https://www.skinnybodycare.com/aff/join" method="post" **id="myform1"**>
    <input type="hidden" value="2skinnyme" name="enroller" />
    <input type="hidden" value="Continue">
    <input type="submit" value="Order Now">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = location.toString().replace(/[&?]2skinnyme=([^&]*)/, '$1');
    document.getElementById('myform1').2skinnyme = myvar;
    document.getElementById('myform1').submit();
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can just submit directly, from the original page, to the URL using AJAX and jquery, but that would require you to be on the same domain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.post('https://www.skinnybodycare.com/aff/join', { enroller: '2skinnyme' }, function() {
        alert('Form has been submitted');
    });
</script>
```